# why is 2/222 called Richie benaud score?

Tags: cricket, terminology

I came to know 2/222 is called Richie Benaud score. Why is it so? Does it have anything to do with his commentary?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does - he has an unusual (to some ears) way of pronouncing the word "two", with a little whistle involved. This has been emphasised by some comedians, particularly Billy Bermingham in his (very funny) 12th Man series.

Comment: Sounds plausible - any references?

Comment: Not without trawling through hours of audio on YouTube - this is comedy. It's all there if you want to listen to it though.

Comment: This is not just "plausible" it is absolutely the case.   Richie says "chew for chew cwenty chew'.   However, it's not so noticeable or consistent that it would have become famous without the mimicry of "The 12th Man" comedy series.   Billy Birmingham mastered the art of mimicing Richie and emphasising that phrase so it was funny and memorable.  http://www.foxsports.com.au/cricket/richie-benaud-12th-man-billy-birmingham-tribute-to-the-greatest-of-cricket-commentators/story-e6frf3g3-1227298360109

Comment: Just to follow this up: you can hear Richie utter the score here, (wonderfully at 2:00 in the video) https://youtu.be/vsOVaq2B4fE?t=2m  ... nothing remarkable really.  It's when you hear the mimicry that it really takes hold (haven't found an example of that yet!)